# I need to create an Excel cell with date format of 22 Feb 2005 - 23 Mar 2005 , how can I do this?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, windows-10

I can easily create the dates in the correct format in different columns, but need the dates combined in one coloumn

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, do you mean entering date range in a cell (`22 Feb 2005 - 23 Mar 2005` in one cell)? If yes you can enter it only as text (so no format setting is necessary / possible)

Answer (score 2):

Whet the following formula, I created the below result:

```
=TEXT(C11,"dd-mmm-yyyy")&" - "& TEXT(D11,"dd-mmm-yyyy")
```

[image]